# Diacritical mark on arabic script in Android moves

Tags: android, native, typeface

I have a native android app i'm developing which has arabic script usage. I have a TextView containing an arabic word which has diacritical marks on it. In android studio the word renders correctly however when I run it on a huawei device one of the diacritical marks jumps into the wrong position. This does not happen on Samsung devices interestingly enough.

[image]